# How to Navigate to separate URL in react router Dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, web, url, react-router, url-routing

i am making a validation form , with a function that checks for password and email , if true it should navigate to a separate website (not to a path within the web). But it is not working

This is my code below:

```
function validate() {
    if (email==='123@123.com' && password==="123456"){
        console.log(email);
 history('http://www.dummy.com/webmail')
}
}

return{
.
.
.
<Button className={stylesAuth.submitButton} variant="warning" onClick={validate}>
}
```

How should I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're redirecting to an external website, you can simply use plain old JavaScript and do a:

```
window.location.href = "https://www.dummy.com/webmail";
```

For more information, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href.

A little bit more information: using `history` doesn't make sense in this case, it is only meant for internal navigation within your web application. In fact, you cannot even push an external URL onto the history stack:

> The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Comment: Yes got it! it worked thanks